# Using protobuf-net to serialize data in viewstate and in Page.Cache

Tags: serialization, viewstate, protobuf-net

Is there a way to use protobuf-net to improve viewstate (size and serialization/deserialization speed) or decrease size of data cached in Page.Cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I honestly haven't tried. I have looked at cache/session-state, but to be frank view-state is something I've always turned off, or avoided via MVC. So I lack some of the familiarity! I suspect, however, that it is rather key-heavy; with those keys being fundamental to retrieval and not fixed. This makes it very hard to package efficiently as protobuf (which works best when the data is predictable ahead of time).

My gut says "not a good fit". And then it says "meh, horrible view-state is".

Comment: I hate viewstate also. But I have project with large viewstate that I cannot turn off, so I'm searching for some improcvements. But you are right - using protobuf could be very hard with unpredictable data like viewstate.